# Simple Web App with Dart and Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I would like to write a simple web app to test some concepts with Dart and Polymer.

The Web app has only few elements and the logic is simple.

The first element is a button, pressing the button a counter is increased by one.

Under the button there is a List of Years with the sum of counter. Touching one year the app scroll down to the months and touching the months down to days.

My issue is that I have no experience with Polymer and I would like to have some advice on which UI Elements I should use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. Good SO questions are about a concrete programming problem including code that shows what you already tried and easily allows to reproduce the problem you run into.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at ... [Polymer.dart Code lab](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/polymer/)?

Note that polymer dart is a dart-port package.